# How to draw a progress indicator on the background of a cell in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios9, calayer

I would like to draw rectangles in the background of the cells of a table view, whose size will indicate the progression of subsequent tasks:

[image]

The progression bar should take the *whole height* of the cell and its width will be programmatically set when the `TableView` is shown.

I would like to know how to get this result with a simple and efficient approach. I have not been able to find good practices for drawing a custom background for `UITableViewCell`s, using `CALayer` or another solution.

Also, I would appreciate if the technical solution for this task could also be valid when deciding to animate the progression of the bars.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution without calculation is that, prepare a set of *static* different background images, and set them depend on the progress value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this does not seem like an elegant and scalable solution to me. I need to be able to modify the color and opacity of the progress bar, as well as provide fluid animations.

Comment: Can't see why it's not elegant at all. You can still change the color and opacity to the image via code.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution requires you to create Progress view programmatically in table view's cellForRowAtIndex method and add to cell.contentView as subview

```
UIProgressView *progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] init];
[progressView setFrame:cell.frame];
[cell.contentView insertSubview:progressView atIndex:0];
```

You can make progressview alpha property to 0.5 or some other value in order for your top views in cell.contentView to be visible properly